# Python (Turtle) Remove turtle / arrow

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a basic Pong and I don't understand why the arrow/turtle in the middle of the screen displays.

The paddle on the screen consists of 6x turtle objects stored in `self.paddle`.
I know the problem has something to do with the `p = Paddle()` but I don't understand where the arrow-object is since it seems to not be in the list mentioned above (`print(self.paddle)`).
Can someone enlighten me?

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1000, height=700)

class Paddle(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.paddle = []
        self.create_player_paddle()

    def create_player_paddle(self):
        for pad in range(0, 6):
            x = -480
            y = 30
            p = Turtle(shape="square")
            p.turtlesize(0.5)
            p.penup()
            p.goto(x, y)
            self.paddle.append(p)

        for part in range(len(self.paddle)):
            self.paddle[part].goto(x, y)
            y -= 10
            


p = Paddle()
screen.update()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand where the arrow-object is since it seems to not be
> in the list mentioned above ... Can someone enlighten me?

Normally, a class like `Paddle()` either *isa* `Turtle` or *contains* one or more instances of `Turtle`.  But you've done both, it is both a `Turtle` (the source of your mystery arrow) and it contains a `list` of turtles.  The simple fix is to remove `Turtle` as its superclass and remove the `super().__init__()` code:

```
class Paddle():

    def __init__(self):
        self.paddle = []
        self.create_player_paddle()
```

Below is my rework of your code addressing the above and other issues I saw:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Paddle():

    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_player_paddle()

    def create_player_paddle(self):
        x = -480
        y = 30

        for _ in range(6):
            segment = Turtle(shape='square')
            segment.turtlesize(0.5)
            segment.penup()
            segment.goto(x, y)

            self.segments.append(segment)

            y -= 10

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1000, height=700)

paddle = Paddle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

The usual approach to a Pong game in turtle is to make the paddle a subclass of `Turtle` and then use `shapesize()` to stretch the turtle to be the rectangle you desire.  But this has issues with collision detection.  Your approach makes the paddle somewhat more complicated, but might work better collision-detection-wise as you can test each segment.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you!
I did the snake game and did an approach where I moved the segments relative to the "head" segment and figured I could do the same for the paddles, but I like your suggestion as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to hide the Turtle pointer, put `Turtle.hideturtle(self)` in your constructor init function